# Switching Off JSONLoader default texture checking?

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, texture-mapping

I am loading a texture from a different location but JSONLoader automatically loads texture from a directory. Is there an option to make JSONLoader skip its default texture loading?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to achieve this

jsonLoader.load('model.js', addModelToScene);

```
function addModelToScene(geometry) {
            var wall_lamp_texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(obj_path + "bathroom/bathroom_lamp_texture.jpg");
            var wallLampMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                map: wall_lamp_texture,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide
            });
            wall_lamp_model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, wallLampMaterial);
            wall_lamp_model.position.set(wallWidth / 2, wallHeight - 150, 0);
            wall_lamp_model.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 2;
            wall_lamp_model.scale.set(5, 5, 5);
            scene.add(wall_lamp_model);
        }
```

Comment: I think this won't work. I made it work by writing a custom wrapper on top of jsonloader.load() function.